# What does a leading single quote mean?

Tags: types, syntax, idris, single-quotes

A name preceded by a `'` character is of type `Type`:

```
Idris> 'foo
'foo : Type
```

**What does this mean?** What would be an example of a value of type `'foo`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A leading single quote in front of a string value converts that string to a type. It is a built-in syntax extension defined in `prelude/Builtins.idr`

```
||| For 'symbol syntax. 'foo becomes Symbol_ "foo"
data Symbol_ : String -> Type where
```

If I understand it correctly symbols do not have a value, but only exist at the type level.

One use case for symbols is documented in the idris documentation: http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/effects/state.html?highlight=symbol where symbols are used to tag states with otherwise identical type signature.